# Full url from tornado request python with hashes

Tags: python, tornado

Hello got a Tornado request.

```
http://localhost:8000/blah/blah#myparameter=value1
```

in my get method i am trying to extract myparameter value. 
get_argument does not see it. Why whould it?
nothing in headers

I am willing to regex it out of the string if i could. I just need url in a string

Comment: Browsers don't send the URL fragment to your server in the first place. You could use some JavaScript solution to send it via AJAX.

Comment: Can't you make it be http://localhost:8000/blah/blah?myparameter=value1 ?

Comment: some other service responds by appending #+params to the redirect url

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution, the tip is to use a `form` with a hidden `id` :

template:

```
<form action="/info">
<input type="hidden" value="your_value" name="id">
<input type="submit" value="Value Result">
</form>
```

and the tornado code:

```
class Info(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        id = self.get_argument("id")
        # the rest of the code
```

the url mapping:

```
(r"/info/*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)*", handlers.Info)
```